# ActionBar onClick listener- this is possible?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How to get ActionBar onClick listener? I mean- global listener for whole view, not only ActionBar child views

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a custom view.

1. Create the `layout` you want for your action bar
2. Add the `android:onClick` attribute in the xml

   android:onClick="handleClick"
3. inflate it somewhere in your code
4. use `ActionBar.setCustomView()` method
5. Implement the `onClick` method in your Java

   ```
   public void handleClick(View view) {
       // code after click here
   }
   ```

That should work !